# Open a file on an SD card with a space in its name

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open a file on an SD card with this code but it gives me force close. When I run my app, this works fine when I use a path like: `sdcard/path/path`

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/path/pa th");
```

I also tried with :

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/path/pa\\ th");
```

and

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/pa th");
```

**How can I open a file that contains a space in the filename?**

Comment: What Exception you get? Provide stacktrace.

Comment: its gives me runtime error (force close)

Comment: Edit the stack trace into your question. Also, your wording isn't extremely clear.

Comment: Instead of using spaces, why not use `_`?

Comment: Best to just not use filenames with spaces if possible, but if you must, how about

`File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/path/pa\ th");`